# Infinite loop for higher values of fibonacci calculation using Big Integer?

Tags: java, biginteger

I've written a program to calculate fibonacci series, it is working fine for lower values but it is stuck in an infinite loop for higher values. Here is the code,

```
public static BigInteger fib(BigInteger n) {
    // ...
    // ...
    
    if(n.intValue() == 0){
      return BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    }
    
    if(n.intValue() == 1){
      return BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    }
    
    if(n.intValue() > 0){
        return calp(n);
      }
    return caln(n);
  }
  
  static BigInteger calp(BigInteger n){
   
    BigInteger prev1 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    BigInteger prev2 = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    
    int i=2;        
    while(i <= n.intValue()){
            BigInteger curr = BigInteger.valueOf(0);

       curr= curr.add(prev1);
       curr = curr.add(prev2);
      prev2=prev1;
      prev1=curr;
      i++;
    }
    return prev1;
  }
```

For value 1234567, it is stuck in an infinite loop. Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: I would guess it could have something to do with the numbers getting to large for a primitive int and overflowing. You seem to have considered that problem already by using `BigInteger` but then kind of defeat that usage by calling `intValue()` on your `BigInteger` multiple times for comparing it. Have you tried using the `BigIntegers `compareTo` method for you checks instead of converting back to a primitive that it might not fit in?

Answer (score 2):

Your program is not stuck in a loop, it's just slow.

Fibonacci number sequence grows *exponentially*. The 1234567th Fibonacci number is approximately

```
7.84468471036091254428371992991734957118403295643488... × 10^258008
```

Calculating with numbers this big will take a lot of time, especially if you are using the inefficient Fib(n+1) = Fib(n) + Fib(n-1) algorithm.

It would be faster to use an approach based on the doubling identity. The idea is, that when given Fib(n) you can compute Fib(2n) directly, skipping all the intermediate values. The details are of course a little more complicated. Here's a good article I found https://chunminchang.github.io/blog/post/calculating-fibonacci-numbers-by-fast-doubling

Comment: My favorite is [this exposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368738/552). Although a little mathy for some, the use of a more complete "multiplication" function leads to very clear and concise code in the form of the `power` and `mult` functions.

Answer (score 0):

one reason that is potentially dangerous is the fact that you unpack BingIntegers to int and compare them,

you should instead use the [compare method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo(java.math.BigInteger))

```
BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
     
while(i.compareTo(n) < 0){
        BigInteger curr = BigInteger.ZERO;//BigInteger.valueOf(0);
```

Comment: This is 'dangerous', but that would not lead to this specific pasted code ever getting stuck in an infinite loop. For input 1234567, at any rate.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an infinite loop. I ran your program, fed it `1234567` and it runs fine. It's just slow. The code does a couple of things which are suspect, and a couple of things which cause things to be slow.

The suspect part (and a lot of the slowness) is that you keep switching between int and BigInteger. This is doubly problematic; the conversion is not neccessarily cheap, and your code can't actually handle large numbers (larger than the int limits of [-2^31, 2^31-1]) very well because you keep converting back to int.

Don't call `intValue()` **anywhere**. Instead, convert your constants such as `1` and `0` to `BigInteger`, such as with `BigInteger.ZERO` (that's better than `BigInteger.valueOf(0)`, too), and use `bi.compareTo` instead of `<=`.

But, those things do not explain why this infinite loops.. and it doesn't infinite loop (just takes long). If you want, print `i` in your while loop, every 100 iterations to show you that it does progress and eventually exit. Add:

```
if (i % 100 == 0) System.out.println(i);
```

inside the while. You'll find it hits 1234500 and then exit.